# .NET negative lookbehind regex not working as expected

Tags: .net, regex, negative-lookbehind

I want to isolate the initials "Wrs" in the string

```
"agendapunt 5.4 (GAIA) asdf <BR>    Wrs    <BR>         medegedeeld"
```

This is the regular expression I'm using:

```
(?<!<BR>)(\s{2,}[a-z]+\s{2,})(?=<BR>)
```

The initials "Wrs" must be followed by atleast two spaces and after that an html break `<BR>`. 
Also the initials "Wrs" must be preceded by atleast two spaces and must NOT be preceded by an HTML `<BR>` tag.

Unfortunately, in the above example, there's still a positive match for the initials, even with the preceding `<BR>` tag. 
I don't understand why, cause the postive lookahead does seem to work as I would expect.
I.E. when I'm removing the second `<BR>` tag, or part of it, from the input string, then there's no match to be found.

Also, I tried using a positive lookbehind instead of a negative one just to see what it would do and it also works exactly as I would expect. 
It seems like positive and negative lookarounds don't work by the same rules in the case.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: would this regex work to isolate Wrs? `<BR>\s*(.*?)\s*<BR>`

Comment: It might be illuminating if you looked at the Value of the match. I'm guessing that it's only matching *three* spaces before `Wrs`, not all four. Those three spaces are not, in fact, preceded by `<BR>`, so they satisfy your regex. Negative lookbehind is tricky.

Answer (score 0):

The regex you are looking for is

```
(?<!<BR>\s{2,})(?<=\s{2,})([a-z]+)(?=\s{2,}<BR>)
```

with an `IgnoreCase` option.

The reason is that we must match the spaces, too, if they are allowed, after the disallowed `<BR>`. Lookbehinds do not consume text, so, in a look-behind, we need to check all the preceding characters before the first consumed one.

I hope it is clearer now.

See [example](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3C!%3CBR%3E%5Cs%7B2%2C%7D)(%3F%3C%3D%5Cs%7B2%2C%7D)(%5Ba-z%5D%2B)(%3F%3D%5Cs%7B2%2C%7D%3CBR%3E)&i=agendapunt%205.4%20(GAIA)%20asdf%20%3CBR%3E%20%20%20%20Wrs%20%20%20%20%3CBR%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20medegedeeld%0D%0Aagendapunt%205.4%20(GAIA)%20asdf%20%20%20%20Wrs%20%20%20%20%3CBR%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20medegedeeld&o=i).